# ipython in emacs -- open help in separate file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ipython

Rather than having the contents of a long help() call to a function print in the ipython shell buffer, is it possible to specify that the contents should be opened in a separate buffer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct way to do what you're asking. As an alternative, you may be able to use [pylookup](http://taesoo.org/Opensource/Pylookup), which will open python help docs in your browser.

Comment: Nice (esp. with w3m option), but so slowww!